# MediaElement.js - HTML5 Audio and Video How to Use in Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, audio, mediaelement.js, autostart

I have installed the [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) - HTML5 Audio and Video plugin in Wordpress. I don't know how to proceed from here to place the audio player in a post and then link an audio file. I have activated the plugin.

This is the code, the player shows up

```
[audio src="http://dsp.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Crazy-Love-VM.mp3"]
```

I would like for this to autostart when the post is opened and play once, not loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[audio src="http://dsp.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Crazy-Love-VM.mp3" autoplay="true"]
```

For more properties, see [the plugin page in WordPress.org](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-element-html5-video-and-audio-player/).